GoogleClassroomにてAPI関数を使用し、異なるドメインの生徒を追加する方法
GoogleClassroomにてAPI関数を使用し、異なるドメインの生徒を直接追加することは可能なのでしょうか？
[現在できていること]
・異なるドメインの生徒の招待
・同一ドメインの生徒の直接追加
Google管理コンソールにて、信頼できるドメインの許可リストには対象ドメインは追加しております。
